# Notation and result

Tags: javascript, arrays, notation

I have to create and array given  a number (n). The array will have all the numbers up to and including that number, but excluding zero.
I wrote the following code

```js
function upTonArr(n) {
    for (var i = 0, monkeys = []; i <= n; monkeys.push(++i)); 
    return monkeys;
}
```

but had to change it for i < n in order for the test to pass.

Can someone please tell me why if "n" needs to be included in the array the notation does not require i to be <=n?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The loop runs if `i` is less or equal to `n`, if you remove the equal part, the loop only runs when `i` is less than `n`, making one less iteration.

Comment: Just try to evaluate each expression in your mind: how many monkeys will get created if I pass `n=0`?

Comment: Agree. If i say that n = 10 then my array should include all numbers from 1- 10, correct?  which is why I'm thinking n <= 10. The testes only passed when the notation said i < n and so I would expect the array to stop at 9.

Comment: Because `++i` increments first then gives the value (*notice it starts at 1 rather than 0*), so you need to stop at `n-1` for it to give `n` as the last array item.

Comment: I understand now. Thank for clarifying @SpencerWieczorek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a prefix operator (++i). What that does is it increments the variable before fetching it. On the first run, the value is 0, but because of the prefix operator, 1 gets pushed to the array. If you had i <= n, it would be pushing (n + 1) as the last value to the array.

The other version, the postfix operator (i++), will first fetch the variable and then increment it after accessing it, so 0 would be pushed to the array on the first run.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.